# Optimizacion de codigo con recursividad en java

Tags: java

En clase tuvimos una prueba en la cual debíamos realizar un programa que permita calcular la potencia de un numero, tanto para números con base positiva o negativa y tanto para exponentes positivos y negativos, solo que con **recursividad**.
Logre formar parte de los 6 únicos que lo terminaron, pero quería saber si existía alguna mejor manera de llevarlo, ya que de la manera que lo realicé a mi parecer es un poco rustica

dejo el código:

```
    public double potencia(int base, int exponente){

        if(base<0)
        {
            int b = base *-1;
            int e= exponente ;

            if(e==0){
                return 1;
            } else if (e<0) {
                return potencia(b, e+1) / b;
            } else {
                return (b * potencia(b, e-1))*-1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(exponente==0){
                return 1;
            } else if (exponente<0) {
                return potencia(base, exponente+1) / base;
            } else {
                return base * potencia(base, exponente-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Que la base sea positiva o negativa da igual, no afecta al problema y se trata exactamente igual.

Que el exponente sea positivo o negativo se puede reducir a "si es negativo, calcula el exponente positivo y al final obtén la inversa del número calculado con el exponente negativo." Es decir, 4<sup>-5</sup> es lo mismo que 1/4<sup>5</sup>.

Así que, en la primera invocación, reduces el problema general a calcular el valor con exponente positivo; cuando salgas de la primera invocación aplicas la inversa si el exponente era negativo.

```
 public double exp(double base, int exponente) {

   if (exponente == 0) {
      return 1d;  // Por definición.
   }

   boolean positivo = true;
   if (exponente < 0) {
      positivo = false;
      exponente = -exponente;
   }

   double calculoEnPositivo = base * exp(base, exponente - 1);

   if (positivo) { // positivo solo puede ser false en la primera invocación.
      return calculoEnPositivo;
   } else {
      return 1/calculoEnPositivo;
   }
}
```

También se puede hacer en dos pasos si eso te simplifica leer el código, una función que solo "ajusta" el exponente y luego la función que calcula el exponente "clásico".

```
public double exp(double base, int exponente) {

   if (exponente >= 0) {
      return expPositivo(base, exponente);
   }
   return 1/expPositivo(base, -exponente);
}

private double expPositivo(double base, int exponente) {

   if (exponente == 0) {
      return 1d;  // Por definición.
   }
   // Aquí sabemos que exponente es > 0 
   return base * expPositivo(base, exponente - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Y qué tal esta solución?

```java
public static double potencia(int base, int exponente){
    if (exponente == 0) { // Caso base
        return 1;
    }
    else if (exponente < 0) { // Caso recursivo, si exponente es negativo, calculamos la inversa de si fuera positivo.
        return 1 / potencia(base, -exponente);
    }
    else { // Caso recursivo, base * base^(exponente-1)
        return base * potencia(base, exponente - 1);
    }
}
```

```java
potencia(3, 3); // Devuelve 27
potencia(-3, 3); // Devuelve -27
potencia(-3, -3); // Devuelve -0.037037037... (aquí tu código devuelve un erróneo 0.037037037...)
potencia(3, -3); // Devuelve 0.037037037...
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto sería con un for:

```
private double funcionPotencia(double base, double exponente) {
        double resultado = 1;
        double exponentePositivo = Math.abs(exponente);
        for (double i = 1; i <= exponentePositivo; i++) {
            resultado *= base;
        }
        if (exponente==0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (exponente<0) {
            return 1/resultado;
        } else {
            return resultado;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Considero que seria mejor con iteración como un "for" o un "while" ya que la recursividad casi siempre es costosa para el procesamiento de datos...

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega lo que tengas implementado. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask